# PNG images not displaying in react native android api 16 and 17

Tags: react-native

when i use PNG format picture with the size of 200 kilobyte it shows perfectly in all API level both on device and emulator but when i use image with the size of less than 1 kilobyte it will not display on API 16 and 17 android emulator or device.

Comment: Could you give us more information? Please specify methods or third-party libraries which you use in your project. Please also use best practices to ask community to get a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i dont think it is related to my third libraries because it works well on android 8 and 9 both in emulator and device. how ever these are my third party libraries:
@react-native-community/async-storage
@react-native-community/netinfo
axios
moment
react-native-collapsible-header-views
react-native-device-info
react-native-elements
react-native-firebase
react-native-gesture-handler
react-native-modal-selector
react-native-snap-carousel
react-navigation
redux
react-redux